# R Automatic Regressions

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

```
data1=mtcars
CONTROL = c("mpg", "cyl")
X = c("hp","drat","wt","am")
Y = c("vs")

model1= glm(vs ~ hp + mpg + cyl, family = binomial, data = data1)
model2= glm(vs ~ drat + mpg + cyl, family = binomial, data = data1)
model3= glm(vs ~ wt + mpg + cyl, family = binomial, data = data1)
model4= glm(vs ~ am + mpg + cyl, family = binomial, data = data1)
```

I can run all of the models by themself but I am hoping to do this automatically because I have to do this for almost a hundred regressions. This is my attempt,

```
i=1:4
model <- vector("list", length(i))
for(1:i){
  model[i]=glm(Y~X[i]+CONTROL,family = binomial, data = data1)
}
```

My desired output would be a dataframe such that:

```
VARNAME COEF LL UL
hp
drat
wt
am
```

Comment: How are you defining "all the models"? Do you want all models with 3 variables? Or all models with one, two, or three variables? With two-way interaction terms? 3-way interaction terms, more?

Comment: @Gregor Thomas thank you so much "all the models" refers to the example I show for model1-4. I have a list of control variables that is constant and then the list of additional predictors; there is no interaction terms

Comment: Okay, so models with all of the `CONTROL` variables and one variable from `X`?

Comment: And  what is LL?  log likelihood?  Also please fix the question so that it can stand by itself without reference to the comments.

Answer (score 1):

We assume you want to regress vs against all sets of 3 variables out of 4 in X plus the control variables.

Also the outline of desired output is unclear so we will assume you want the coefficients of each model along with some other unspecified statistics and we use log likelihood as an example.  Each output row represents results from one model run with the NA in each row showing which coefficient was not used.

No packages are used.

```
# test data is the builtin mtcars as well as CONTROL, X and Y
CONTROL <- c("mpg", "cyl")
X <- c("hp","drat","wt","am")
Y <- "vs"

stats <- function(nm) {
  fo <- reformulate(c(setdiff(X, nm), CONTROL), Y)
  fm <- glm(fo, mtcars, family = binomial)
  coefs <- c(coef(fm), setNames(NA, nm))[c("(Intercept)", X)]
  c(coefs, logLik = logLik(fm))  # add other statistics to this line
}

do.call("rbind", lapply(X, stats))
```

giving this matrix:

```
     (Intercept)          hp        drat        wt         am        logLik
[1,]   150.84593          NA   -4.381111  2.242363  -62.74444 -2.338630e+00
[2,]   137.24734 -0.01079679          NA  1.209804  -60.16064 -2.826391e+00
[3,]  3285.91281 -6.54621462 -344.866970        NA -311.77291 -1.315947e-08
[4,]    84.76241 -0.49550208  -25.801081 24.231253         NA -3.863991e+00
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets you most of the way there:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

char_formula = sprintf("%s ~ %s + %s", Y, paste(CONTROL, collapse = "+"), X)

mods = list()
for(i in seq_along(char_formula)) {
  mods[[i]] = glm(as.formula(char_formula[i]), family = binomial, data = data1)
}

names(mods) = X
lapply(mods, tidy) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "VARNAME") %>%
  filter(term %in% X)
# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#   VARNAME term  estimate  std.error statistic p.value
#   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 hp      hp     -0.0461     0.0362  -1.27      0.203
# 2 drat    drat   -2.53       1.83    -1.38      0.168
# 3 wt      wt      2.26       1.73     1.30      0.192
# 4 am      am    -61.0    18184.      -0.00335   0.997
```